# Parsing XML data in Hive when few elements are there in tag and not in another tag

Tags: xml, xpath, hive

Below is the XML snippet:

```
<employment source="file">
<employer>
    <unparsed>EMPLOYER-2</unparsed>
</employer>
<fileDate>2020-07-21</fileDate>
<effDate>2020-07-21</effDate>
</employment>
<employment source="file">
<employer>
    <unparsed>EMPLOYER-1</unparsed>
</employer>
<occupation>NURSE</occupation>
<hiredDate>2006-09-01</hiredDate>
<fileDate>2015-08-07</fileDate>
<effDate>2015-08-07</effDate>
</employment>
```

In the above code, XML has employment information. The info is above 2 employers , but tags under employment are not same. Ex: Employe-2 dont have "hiredDate and occupation" info but employer-1 has. Need logic to pull data from XML file as below format:

[image]

I tried using explode and posexplode but no luck.

Comment: added the answer please check and let me know for help!

Comment: have you considered using XSL for this? it would be the easiest option.

Comment: @BrynLewis XSL?? could you eloborate?

Comment: @vishnuSarat, could you heck the below answer is helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

below steps might be helpful,

1. use the hivexmlserde from Maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml/hivexmlserde
2. copy the input xml file to hive external table pointing hdfs

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal emp.xml /stackoverflow/data/hive/dwh/employee`

3. add the xml serde jar into hive terminal and create ddl and proceed as below.

```
add jars file:///home/sathya/Downloads/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
Added [file:///home/sathya/Downloads/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar] to class path
Added resources: [file:///home/sathya/Downloads/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar]


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE employee (
`employer_name` string,
`occupation` string,
`hiredDate` string,
`fileDate` string,
`effDate` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.employer_name"="/employment/employer/unparsed/text()",
"column.xpath.occupation"="/employment/occupation/text()",
"column.xpath.hiredDate"="/employment/hiredDate/TillNo/text()",
"column.xpath.fileDate"="/employment/fileDate/text()",
"column.xpath.effDate"="/employment/effDate/text()"
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' 
    LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:9000/stackoverflow/data/hive/dwh/employee'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
    "xmlinput.start"="<employment","xmlinput.end"="</employment>"
);

select * from employee;

EMPLOYER-2  NULL    NULL    2020-07-21  2020-07-21
EMPLOYER-1  NURSE   NULL    2015-08-07  2015-08-07
```