# How to include metadata in spark dataframe when reading xml

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read a set of xml files into a spark dataframe. I am able to read in the core row level data, but I would also like to include some additional data that is stored at the top of each file into the rows. What is the best approach for this?

xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx creator="StravaGPX" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
 <metadata>
  <time>2020-08-09T16:30:33Z</time>
 </metadata>
 <trk>
  <name>Afternoon Run</name>
  <type>9</type>
  <trkseg>
   <trkpt lat="51.3474380" lon="-0.3649680">
    <ele>57.4</ele>
    <time>2020-08-09T16:30:33Z</time>
    <extensions>
     <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
      <gpxtpx:hr>102</gpxtpx:hr>
      <gpxtpx:cad>0</gpxtpx:cad>
     </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
    </extensions>
   </trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="51.3474380" lon="-0.3649690">
    <ele>57.4</ele>
    <time>2020-08-09T16:30:34Z</time>
    <extensions>
     <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
      <gpxtpx:hr>102</gpxtpx:hr>
      <gpxtpx:cad>0</gpxtpx:cad>
     </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
    </extensions>
   </trkpt>
 </trk>
</gpx>
```

The code i have so far is:

```
df = spark.read.format(file_type).option("rowTag", "trkpt").option("rootTag", "trk").option("nullValue", "").load(file_location)
```

Using this, I am able to get all of the data that is stored in the trkprt tags. How do I also get the higher level data from the trk tag and include it in each row for the relevant file?

Comment: you want to take `creator`, `metadata`, `time`, `trk.name`,`trk.type` details?

Comment: trk.name, trk.type, metadata.time

Comment: can you try with the `hivexmlserde` and see that works for you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63287427/parsing-xml-data-in-hive-when-few-elements-are-there-in-tag-and-not-in-another-t/63291192#63291192

Comment: i'm not sure this is applicable as I don't have the infrastructure for hive?